# Has the Chromedriver automation extension ID changed with version 2.32? Or it is still 'aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb'?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver

The Chromedriver 2.32 change log states that "Changes to the way automation extension is loaded on Mac and Windows"(https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).

We had white-listed the extension 'aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb', and we were able to use Chromedriver 2.28 to 2.31 as a result. But now when I tried to switch to 2.32, I'm getting the same 'Loading of unpacked extensions is disabled by administrator' error.

Has the extension ID changed?

Do we have to change the way the white-listing is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We also met this issue `Loading of unpacked extensions is disabled by the administrator` when we move from Win 7 to Win 10.

Due to company policy reason, IT admin disable `load unpacked extension` on Win 10.

We did some search and found a solution say adding the `Chrome Automation Extension` to **Chrome Extension White List** by modifying **Windows Registry**. We will get a long wait before approve by security department.

So we find another solution to disable Chrome to load that extension:

```
// this code for Protractor, if you use java/python, please change accordingly
capabilities: {
    browserName: "chrome",
    chromeOptions: {
        // add this into chromOptions to disable load the extension
        useAutomationExtension: false, 
    }
},
```

With above chromeOptions, eelow script to operate window size and take screenshot also work well:

```
browser.manage().window().setSize(600, 800);        
browser.manage().window().maximize();
```

I did deep search, the window size/position, screenshot supported by that extension on earlier Chrome, but since Chrome 59 which support headless model, the window size/position, screenshot also supported by DevTool protocol.

So I think since Chrome 59, we no need that extension.

And you can open `chrome://policy` in Chrome to check extension black/white/force list

[image]